# Grails, infinite loop when rejectIfNoRule = true

Tags: grails

I have problem with infinite loop in Grails app when `rejectIfNoRule = true`
I try to open home page '/' and I am redirected to '/login/auth' with an error

> Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many
>   redirects.

It seems like the source of the problem is located in initialize method in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.RequestmapFilterInvocationDefinition.java where following exception is silenced.

```
Exception initializing; this is ok if it's at startup and due to GORM not being initialized yet since the first web request will re-initialize. Error message is "Cannot load Requestmaps, \"requestMap.className\" property is not set
```

Unfortunately the first request is this one with infinite loop so how can I initialize Requestmap for GORM?

Environment:

- Groovy Version: 2.0.6
- Grails 2.2.0
- JVM: 1.7.0_07 Vendor: Oracle Corporation
- OS: Linux
- spring-security-core:1.2.7.3
- spring-security-ui:0.2

My Config.groovy:

- grails.plugins.springsecurity.securityConfigType = "Requestmap"
- grails.plugins.springsecurity.rejectIfNoRule = true

Requestmaps:

```
new Requestmap(url: '/js/**', configAttribute: 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY').save()
new Requestmap(url: '/css/**', configAttribute: 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY').save()
new Requestmap(url: '/images/**', configAttribute: 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY').save()
new Requestmap(url: '/login/**', configAttribute: 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY').save()
new Requestmap(url: '/logout/**', configAttribute: 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY').save()
new Requestmap(url: '/', configAttribute: 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY').save()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Error message is "Cannot load Requestmaps, \"requestMap.className\" property is not set

This is the reason for your error - when you're storing request maps in the database you need an entry in `Config.groovy` telling the spring security plugin the name of the `Requestmap` domain class

```
grails {
  plugins {
    springsecurity {
      securityConfigType = SecurityConfigType.Requestmap

      // fully qualified class name of the Requestmap class
      requestMap.className = 'com.example.Requestmap'

      // these next two are the defaults but good to make them explicit anyway
      requestMap.urlField = 'url'
      requestMap.configAttributeField = 'configAttribute'
    }
  }
}
```